# NtQueryInformationThread sometimes fails, no error code

Tags: c++, windows, memory-address

I want to get the base address of all the threads in the system -- I use `NtQueryInformationThread` with `ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress` for that. It works well for most of the threads in the system, but for a small part of them I get back 0 as the start address.

I am testing it in xp, I am admin, and I added SeDebugPrivilege token to myself, and the threads I am having trouble with, are not system pid's (not pid 0 or 4)

```
DWORD myThreadID = 996
HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, myThreadID);
```

OpenThread Success, hThread is not null;

```
typedef NTSTATUS (WINAPI *pNtQIT)(HANDLE, LONG, PVOID, ULONG, PULONG);
#define ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress 9

pNtQIT NtQueryInformationThread = (pNtQIT)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryInformationThread");
PVOID dwStartAddress; 
NTSTATUS ntStatus = NtQueryInformationThread(hThread, ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress, &dwStartAddress, sizeof(DWORD), NULL);
```

`NtQueryInformationThread()` success, `ntStatus`==0, but `dwStartAddress` is olso 0,

Any ideas?

Comment: The MSDN documentation specifically warns about this, no reason to assume that you got a "wrong" value.  Relying on internal OS functions like this is something you'll regret, if not today, you will not get a meaningful value back on later Windows versions.  Starting with Windows version 6 (Vista and up), you'll get the same value back for every thread.  Don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant For most threads, I get proper value even in Windows 7. besides that, is there another recommended way to get the base address of each thread (as shown in Process Explorer)?

Comment: Mark Russinovich does not share his secrets.